# C# Repeated Image in PictureBox

Tags: c#, image

I am working on a C# piano and have encountered a problem.

I have built the keyboard and the staff, and each key pressed by the user is displayed in its respective position on the staff.

My problem is that the image is repeated beyond the first key (be it any key). For instance, if I press a key the second time, two images are displayed on the staff for that particular key press. If I press a fifth key (be it any key), five images are displayed on the staff.

How do I solve this problem please? I only want to display one image per key. Thanks.

**Edit**

I have solved the problem.  Thanks :)

Comment: your method addPictureBox makes a new image everytime you call it. i think you use it also to make the staff. by calling this function for the notes every time, e new note will be added to the pic, cant you just rewrite the excisting note, removing the cnt++?

Comment: I tried to remove it, but the problem still persists :(

Comment: after rereading the question, you mean you want the second note to appear but when pressing the buttons this happens? (example) pres a,b,c,d,e --> out: a,aab,aababc,aababcd. is this what happens?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling addPictureBox only once for every keypress ?...  I think it somehow gets called for all the keys in the array...

Comment: @Moonlight You are on the right track.  However, if I press a, b, c, d, e this is what happends --> a, bb, ccc, dddd, eeeee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe do something like this, if image.name is unique

```
picBox[cnt].Image = image.Name;
if(!panel3.Controls.Find(image.Name)!=null){ //add contol to panel}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it is guessed that each key press will add an image/picture box to the panel3, this will ultimately consume all resources. You are advised to check if a picture is already there first, and if there are, not to further addPictureBox any longer, but to bring them to front or toggle their visibilities.

BTW: if you want to animate the key press effect, using image is far less efficient, you can consider using OpenGL or DirectX instead.

Comment: Everytime the user presses a key, it should be displayed on the staff, irrelevant whether it was pressed before.

Comment: The program converts the music played to the staff.

Comment: on the staff? what do u mean by that?